# "EBADF: Bad file descriptor" when writing files within a Docker container with Bun/Node

Tags: node.js, docker, filesystems, bun

I'm hosting a simple Bun http app in a docker container (the same exact problem persists when using normal Node.js apis as well, so I don't think it's Bun specific), and I'm trying to write to the file system.

Every time I do so, I get the following error:

```js
EBADF: Bad file descriptor 
fd: "-2"
syscall: "write"
errno: -9

error: uploading initial file failed, unable to write: /usr/src/app/temp/<name-of-file>.gp5, EBADF: Bad file descriptor
```

Here is the code ->

```js
const uploadPath = process.cwd() + `${this.tempFolder}/${Date.now()}__${file.name}`;

try {
  await Bun.write(uploadPath, await file.arrayBuffer());
} catch (error) {
  throw new Error(
    `uploading initial file failed, unable to write: ${uploadPath}, ${error}`
  );
}
```

The `process.cwd()` and `uploadPath` path is also pointing to the correct location of the folder in the Docker file explorer.

Let me know if anyone has encountered this error before